# CORS bloqueando .netCore 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Bom dia, criei uma API em .netCore 3 e fiz todos os testes habilitando CORS e com POSTMAN não tive problemas, porém ao tentar acessara API de um outro computador, estou sendo bloqueado pelo CORS.
No startup.cs, habilitei para poder passar qualquer solicitação.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        //app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

e no request:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/configs")]    
public class ConfiguracaoController : ControllerBase
{
    //Get funciona sem problemas
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Configuracao>>> Get([FromServices] GeradorContext context)
    {
        var configs = await context.Configuracoes
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
        return Ok(configs);
    }
    //PUT ou outro não
    [HttpPut("{Id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Configuracao>> Put([FromServices] GeradorContext context, int id, [FromBody] Configuracao configuracao)
    {

        try
        {
            var configs = await context.Configuracoes
                .AsNoTracking()
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);

            if (configs == null) return NotFound();

            context.Update(configs);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Created($"/api/configs/{configuracao.Id}", configuracao);

        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
        }

    }


}
```

porém estou sendo bloqueado:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.24:8095/api/configs/2' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Isso só não acontece em métodos GET, para os demais(PUT, POST, DELETE) acontece.

Comment: cade a parte do código de conexão ?

Comment: Virgilio, obrigado pela resposta, sou novo nesse mundo, quando você diz "código de conexão", seria a controller onde faço as Requests?

Comment: sim ... aonde está esse código

Comment: Editei e coloquei ele na pergunta.

Comment: no outro computador você está tentando acessar a api a partir do postman? parece ser uma resposta do navegador isso ai, não do back

Comment: No postman fiz testes na mesma máquina com portas difentes, no outro computador estou tentando acessar a API com o Chrome.

Comment: O problema é provavelmente o uso do Chrome, se não me engano ele bloqueia vários recursos quando se usa o localhost

Comment: Acredito que se fosse algum problema com o navegador, nenhum método funcionaria e o GET funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, resolvi o problema, vou postar aqui caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema. Em operações de PUT, POST ou DELETE é necessário desativar o WebDavModule, para isso adicionei no web.config a linha abaixo:

```
            <system.webServer>
                <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
                </modules>
            </system.webServer>
```